# Verilog :errors.Invalid use of input signal <ck> as target

Tags: verilog, hardware, system-verilog, xilinx, fsm

I can't figure out , where this `errors.Invalid use of input signal <ck> as target` error is coming from?

```
module register
  #(parameter  Width = 8)
   (output reg [Width-1:0] out,
    input      [Width-1:0] in,
    input                  clear, load, clock);

 always @(posedge clock)
   if (~clear)
     out<= 0;
  else if (~load)
    out<=in;
endmodule

module adder
  #(parameter Width = 8)
  (input  [Width-1:0]  a,b,
   output [Width-1:0] sum);
   assign sum = a + b;
endmodule


module compareLT // compares a < b
  #(parameter Width = 8)
  (input  [Width-1:0] a, b,
   output             out);
   assign  out = a < b;
endmodule

module compareLEQ // compares a <= b
  #(parameter Width = 8)
  (input [Width-1:0] a, b,
   output            out);
   assign out = a <= b;
endmodule


module roshanpoop
  #(parameter Width = 8)
   (input                ck, reset,
    input   [Width-1:0]  yln,
    output  [Width-1:0]  y, x);

    wire [Width-1:0] i, addiOut, addxOut;
    wire  yLoad, yClear, xLoad, xClear, iLoad,iClear;

    register  #(Width) I (i, addiOut, iClear, iLoad, ck);
    register  #(Width) Y (y, yIn, yClear, yLoad, ck);
    register  #(Width) X (x, addxOut, xClear, xLoad, ck);

    adder  #(Width)  addI (addiOut, 'b1, i),
    addX (x, y, addxOut);
    compareLT   #(Width)  cmpX (x, 'b0, xLT0);
    compareLEQ  #(Width)  cmpI (i, 'd10, iLEQ10);
    fsm ctl     (xLT0,iLEQ10  ,yLoad, yClear, xLoad, xClear, iLoad,iClear, ck, reset);
endmodule


module fsm
 (input LT,LEQ, ck, reset,
  output reg  yLoad, yClear, xLoad, xClear, iLoad, iClear);
  reg [2:0]  cState, nState;

  always @(posedge ck,negedge reset)
    if (~reset)
      cState <= 0;
    else
      cState <= nState;

  always@(cState, LT,LEQ)
    case (cState)
      3'b00:  begin  //stateA
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 1; xClear = 0;
        iLoad = 1; iClear = 0; nState = 3'b001;
      end
      3'b001: begin  // state B
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 0; xClear = 1;
        iLoad = 0; iClear = 1; nState = 3'b010;
      end
      3'b010: begin  //state C
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 1; xClear = 1;
        iLoad = 1; iClear = 1;
        if(LEQ)         nState = 3'b001;
        if(~LEQ & LT)   nState = 3'b011;
        if (~LEQ & ~LT) nState = 3'b100;
      end
      3'b011:  begin  //state D
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 0; xLoad = 1; xClear = 1;
        iLoad = 1; iClear = 1; nState = 3'b101;
      end
      3'b100: begin  //state E
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 1; xClear = 0;
        iLoad = 1; iClear = 1; nState = 3'b101;
      end
      default: begin // required to satisfy combinational synthesis rules
        yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 1; xClear = 1;
        iLoad = 1; iClear = 1;nState = 3'b000;
        $display("Oops, unknown state: %b", cState);
      end
    endcase
endmodule
```

error:

```
 line no:70
 Invalid use of input signal ck as target,
 Invalid use of input signal target as target.
```

In module roshanpoop above mentioned error are coming . what might be the problem ?

Comment: which tool you are using for simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by this instantiation:

```
fsm ctl     (xLT0,iLEQ10  ,yLoad, yClear, xLoad, xClear, iLoad,iClear, ck, reset);
```

of the module:

```
module fsm
 (input LT,LEQ, ck, reset,
  output reg  yLoad, yClear, xLoad, xClear, iLoad, iClear);
```

You are using positional instantiation, which is not recomended, because it makes the task of maintaining your module more difficult (think, for example, if you want to add signals to your module: if you add it in the middle of the module's definition, all remaining signals will be wrongly connected).

Here, the use of positional instantiation has caused signal `ck` from the top module to be connected to `iLoad`, which is an output signal from `fsm`, so you are trying to put a value to a input only signal `ck`.

The way to have it right is to use explicit instantiation, where each signal from the module is explicitly named and assigned to a signal from the top module, like this:

```
fsm ctl     (.LT(xLT0),
             .LEQ(iLEQ10),
             .yLoad(yLoad),
             .yClear(yClear),
             .xLoad(xLoad),
             .xClear(xClear),
             .iLoad(iLoad),
             .iClear(iClear),
             .ck(ck),
             .reset(reset)
         );
```

So, regardless of where in the argument list you put signal `clk` it will be always connected to the right signal inside the module.

Comment: The fsm could also be instantiated as `fsm ctrl ( .LT(xLT0), .LEQ(iLEQ10), .*);`, where `.*` will auto connect nets of the same name. Some simulators will give errors if there is a bit width mismatch (this is a good error); others will give a warning (check you log file and resolve).

Comment: That is for System Verilog only. Tags indicate it, but the question title says "Verilog", so I have sticked to the preferred instantiation method valid for both Verilog and SVerilog.

Comment: You are correct @mcleod_ideafix, my mistake. I had it in my head that it was part of IEEE Std 1364-2001. I opened my copies of the LRMs and could not find a reference in any IEEE 1364.

Comment: Wish that had been included in plain Verilog. Could have saved me tons of work a while ago, when I was translating a core partially written in SVerilog to plain Verilog. Instantiating submodules with almost a hundred signals using explicit instantiation was a pain :(

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but some tips on potentially making the code easier to understand. I would post as a comment but code examples do not work well in comments.

1) Manual sensitivity lists can [should] be avoided when using a modern toolset.

```
always@(cState, LT,LEQ)
```

With an automatic sensitivity list would just be:

```
always @(*)
// Or 
always @*
```

If you are able to use SystemVerilog (as question tags indicate) then the preferred method is :

```
always_comb
```

2) Instead of:

```
 yLoad = 1; yClear = 1; xLoad = 1; xClear = 0;
 iLoad = 1; iClear = 0;
```

For every case, we could have

```
reg [5:0] temp_control;
assign {yLoad, yClear xLoad, xClear, iLoad, iClear} = temp_control;
//...
always @*
  case(cState) 
    3'b000:  begin  //stateA
        temp_control = 6'b111010; nState = 3'b001;
      end
      3'b001: begin  // state B
        temp_control = 6'b110101; nState = 3'b010;
      end
      3'b010: begin  //state C
        temp_control = 6'b111111;
        if(LEQ)         nState = 3'b001;
        if(~LEQ & LT)   nState = 3'b011;
        if (~LEQ & ~LT) nState = 3'b100;
      end
//...
```

Better still create Mnemonics for the temp_controls.

```
localparam [5:0] CTRL_LOAD  = 6'b111010;
localparam [5:0] CTRL_CLEAR = 6'b111010;
```

Mnemonics for the states are also really helpful:

```
localparam [2:0] STATE_INIT  = 3'b000;
localparam [2:0] STATE_START = 3'b001;
localparam [2:0] STATE_STOP  = 3'b010;
```

The the FSM structure might look some thing like:

```
always @*
  case(cState) 
      STATE_INIT:  begin  //stateA
        temp_control = CTRL_LOAD; nState = STATE_START;
      end
      STATE_START: begin  // state B
        temp_control = CTRL_CLEAR; nState = STATE_STOP;
      end
      STATE_STOP: begin  //state C
        temp_control = CTRL_HALT;
        if(LEQ)         nState = STATE_START;
        if(~LEQ & LT)   nState = STATE_RECYCLE;
        if (~LEQ & ~LT) nState = STATE_CRUSH;
      end
```

As the readability improves it is often easier to spot an incorrectly used signal.

Comment: Since the OP tag the question with SystemVerilog, they should be using `always_comb` instead of `always @*`. always_comb guarantees to execute at time 0(needed when some inputs to the block are constants), and rule checks to guarantee combinational logic are performed.

Comment: True dave_59 since I did not see any SystemVerilog constructs thought they were just wanting plain verilog, will edit answer.